# What is this miniature backpack called?

Tags: backpacks, terminology

When I was in Japan I bought this miniature backpack, about the size of a wallet.  The sporting good store was in Ochanomizu ([御茶ノ水](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ochanomizu)).  It lasted me about 5 years.  Now I am back in the United States and I have trouble finding a new one.

[image]

I can tell the brand is EIGER, but I can't tell what this model is called or if it has been discontinued.  Normal sized backpacks are easy to find, but not this miniature size which fits in your wallet.

As you can see, I stuck a chain and a carob-beaner to attach it to my pants.  That's just using stuff I found at the house and hardware store.

Comment: Try searching for key chain backpack or coin purse backpack.

Answer (score 7):

The closest thing to what you look for are "cpr keychains". You might also search for "mini backpack keychains" to find similar results near you. Here some some stores that offer similar products:

[Schlüsselanhänger mini Rucksack](https://www.werbegeschenk.de/schluesselanhaenger/mit-geldboerse/schluesselanhaenger-mini-rucksack-104124)

[CPR keychain kit (gloves included)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000G7P0LG)

[Sprayground Multi Cam Camo Key Chain](https://www.surfdome.ie/sprayground_chains_-_sprayground_multi_cam_camo_key_chain_-_multi-164354)

[Eastpak POD Small Wallet Key Chain Belt Bag Mini Backpack](http://www.rcworldmalta.com/ourshop/prod_3061742-Eastpak-POD-Small-Wallet-Key-Chain-Belt-Bag-Mini-Backpack.html)

[CPR Keychains](http://www.wholesale-direct-first-aid.com/5057-cpr-keychains)

I tried to link diverse offers to not advertise any shop. Delete or modify this answer if necessary.

OP might want to look for shops in his own country anyway. Maybe you might even find one made by eiger.

Answer (score 5):

Eiger is a Company located in Indonesia and the main distributor in Europe is a company called Mountaintop Sports GmbH which is located in Germany.
You can send them an Email at " [info@eiger-adventure.com](http://seputarjakarta.net/eiger-adventure-store.html) " with a picture and I am guessing that  they will be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

These aren't exactly the style of backpack you asked for, but I knew I'd seen something visually similar.  There are some outdoors camera cases that are basically mini-backpacks with carabiners.  They've even got places on the outside of the packs for attaching more carabiners or other items.  The two best examples I could find are here:

[Ricoh Adventure Case with Carabiner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007P0FZNA)

[Nikon Coolpix All-Weather Case](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Nikon-Coolpix-All-Weather-Sport-Digital-Camera-Case-with-EN-EL12-Battery-Charger-Kit-for-AW100-AW110-AW120-P340-S800c-S9500-S9700/39612857)

As for naming your backpack, I found the most luck when searching for "nylon case with carabiner."

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is probably more likely to be marketed as a 'pouch' than a 'mini-backpack'.

A search for 'belt pouch' or 'utility pouch' on ebay will get you what you want.